# Pointing Temp path to different directory in JasperReports for compiling reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am making a runnable jar of my *JasperReports*' (6.1.0 version) project and running in Unix system. By default the *JasperReports* engine makes a file with **tmp** extension while executing the report in the `/tmp` directory.

I want to direct that path to other directory like `/home/tomcat` and I have tried using the below property in *.jrxml* of my report

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.compiler.temp.dir" value="./home/tomcat"/>
```

but still its not working - the temporary files still created at `/tmp` folder.

Comment: `but still its not working` - What do you mean? What version of JasperReports lib are you using?

Comment: I am using jasperreports-6.1.0.jar

Comment: In eclipse also I tried the same code but still its not working, is there anything in java code which I can write in my class and do the required. And do you want me to share the .jrxml file.

Comment: What do you mean by saying `but still its not working`? What is your expectation?

Comment: Hi Alex, my expectation is that I want that jasper should use my specified path memory for generating the ".tmp" file and not the default path's (i.e., the "/tmp" in unix) memory. Because my "/tmp" directory does not have that enough space to store the temporary file and due to this the report does not generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the research, finally I got it. We simply have to change the value of the `-Djava.io.tmpdir` variable in the run configuration of the application.
Like in my case I had a runnable jar so the command would be:
`java -Djava.io.tmpdir="/your/tempPath" -jar YourJarFileName`
Or we can set the System property through the code in our application by
    `System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir","your\\tempPath");`

Answer (score 1):

The configuration reference for the [`net.sf.jasperreports.compiler.temp.dir`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.compiler.temp.dir) property lists Global as property scope.  That means that it can only be configured globally, setting at report level will not work.

Therefore you'll have to either set the propert in your `jasperreports.properties` file (if you have one) or set it programattically via `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.setProperty()`.

**But**, if you want to avoid the hassle with compiler temporary files, you should add an ECJ jar to your application's classpath (such as [this one](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.3.1/)).  With the ECJ compiler, report compilation will not produce any temporary files.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to set it through program but it is not working, below is the code -> 
`DefaultJasperReportsContext reportsContext=DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();`
      `reportsContext.setProperty(JRPropertiesUtil.PROPERTY_PREFIX+".compiler.temp.dir", "./D:/Files");`

Comment: Use JRCompiler.COMPILER_TEMP_DIR as property name (or JRPropertiesUtil.PROPERTY_PREFIX+‌​"compiler.temp.dir"‌​) as property name.  Also verify that ./D:/Files is properly resolved on your system, it looks a little strange to me.